Interpolation of one column in dataframe based on value in another
I have a dataframe with some data in three columns. It very simplified looks somewhat like this:
data = pd.DataFrame([[500,-90,-0.2],[500,0,0.03],[500,90,0.14],
[1000,-90,-0.12],[1000,0,0.06],[1000,90,0.23],
[5000,-90,-0.32],[5000,0,-0.02],[5000,90,0.2]], 
columns = ['Value_A','Value_B','Value_C'])

   Value_A  Value_B  Value_C
0      500      -90    -0.20
1      500        0     0.03
2      500       90     0.14
3     1000      -90    -0.12
4     1000        0     0.06
5     1000       90     0.23
6     5000      -90    -0.32
7     5000        0    -0.02
8     5000       90     0.20

Then I calculate from some other data Value_A = 2000 and I want to interpolate the data in 'Value_C' for the same values in 'Value_B'. So it becomes:
0     2000      -90    interpolated
1     2000        0    interpolated
2     2000       90    interpolated

I have only done more basic 1-D interpolation before and don't understand how to expand to this example. Please keep in mind that the data actually is around 300 rows. Thank you in advance!

I would pivot to reshape to wide form, then add the extra value(s) A with reindex with method='index' (and with help of pipe + Index.union), then interpolate. Finally, reshape back to original with stack+reset_index:
target = [2000]
val_cols = ['Value_C']

out = (data
  .pivot(index='Value_A', columns='Value_B', values=val_cols)
  .pipe(lambda x: x.reindex(x.index.union(target)))
  .interpolate(method='index')
  .stack().reset_index()
)

Output:
    Value_A  Value_B  Value_C
0       500      -90  -0.2000
1       500        0   0.0300
2       500       90   0.1400
3      1000      -90  -0.1200
4      1000        0   0.0600
5      1000       90   0.2300
6      2000      -90  -0.1700  # interpolated values
7      2000        0   0.0400  #
8      2000       90   0.2225  #
9      5000      -90  -0.3200
10     5000        0  -0.0200
11     5000       90   0.2000

Intermediate before stack:
        Value_C              
Value_B     -90    0       90
Value_A                      
500       -0.20  0.03  0.1400
1000      -0.12  0.06  0.2300
2000      -0.17  0.04  0.2225 # interpolated values
5000      -0.32 -0.02  0.2000

You can easily add more values to interpolate, and handle multiple columns. Example with target = [2000, 3000]:
    Value_A  Value_B  Value_C
0       500      -90  -0.2000
1       500        0   0.0300
2       500       90   0.1400
3      1000      -90  -0.1200
4      1000        0   0.0600
5      1000       90   0.2300
6      2000      -90  -0.1700  # interpolated values
7      2000        0   0.0400  #
8      2000       90   0.2225  #
9      3000      -90  -0.2200  #
10     3000        0   0.0200  #
11     3000       90   0.2150  #
12     5000      -90  -0.3200
13     5000        0  -0.0200
14     5000       90   0.2000

If you just want the new rows, reindex a second time after interpolation:
target = [2000]
val_col = ['Value_C']

out = (data
  .pivot(index='Value_A', columns='Value_B', values=val_col)
  .pipe(lambda x: x.reindex(x.index.union(target)))
  .interpolate(method='index').reindex(target)
  .stack().reset_index()
)

Output:
   Value_A  Value_B  Value_C
0     2000      -90  -0.1700
1     2000        0   0.0400
2     2000       90   0.2225

